# Value will blink only once at the html text box

Tags: javascript, html

`while loop in javascript`

```
function calc(){
var one = document.getElementById("fv").value;
var two = document.getElementById("sv").value;
var one1 = parseInt(one); 
var two1 = parseInt(two);
var total = 0;
if(one1<=two1){
while (one1 <= two1){
total = total+one1;
one1++;                         
total=total;
}
document.getElementById("tv").value = total;
}}
calc() //call function
</script>
<form>
```

There are some confusion using while loop in java script. can i use while loop for those type of calculation?

```
<p>"Calculation of sum between two numbers"</p>
<h5>First Number</h5><input type ="text" value="1" name="firstv" id="fv"><br>
<h5>Second Number</h5><input type="text" value="100" name="sectv" id="sv"><br>
<h5>Value</h5><input type="number" value= "" name="tv" id="tv"><br>
<button onclick="calc()" value="click">Calculate</button><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: question doesn't clearly says what you want

Comment: putting this on jsfiddle will greatly help with what you want to do  and for us to help you.

Comment: @AnshulNigam # i need to calculate sum between 1 to 100 i.e. 5050, display into text filed named by "tv". it is't working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the button from actually submitting the form.  If you make sure that your Javascript function appears before your html and your button looks like this:

```
<button onclick="calc(); return false;" value="click">Calculate</button>
```

Then it should work properly

If you need to call the first calc() before the button is clicked, you need to do it when the document is ready:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   calc();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lwupe6m/1)